# #UWP# Unable to activate Windows Store App, with error 'Invalid value for registry'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

An error occurs when I try to debug my UWP app with Visual Studio Update 1.

The message shown on the screen:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app '{your app package family name}'.
> The activation request failed with error 'Invalid value for registry'.
>
> See help for advice on troubleshooting the issue.

The message box looks like:

[image]

Then I clicked the "Help" button.
The url of the page it points to is
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Areas/Epx/Content/500.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/query/dev14.query

The page content is

> **Unable to Service Request**
>
> For the latest headlines and to see what's new, visit the MSDN home page.
>
> Check out the various MSDN Developer Centers where you can find the latest product information, technical resources, and community offerings.
>
> Visit the MSDN Library for the latest technical articles, reference documentation, downloads, and more.

Any idea?

Comment: In case your app was deploying earlier. Did you uninstall app before deploying. Try to change build type to Release or else wait for some time sometimes its registry elements are still left after uninstall.

Comment: Thanks @Jerin, I'll give it a go and report back...

Comment: Hi @Jerin, I did everything you suggested. but it's still showing the same error. Like you said there're some registry entries are still left. And I tried to manually remove those entries, but for failed with some access denied error or etc. My guess is those entries are some how locked when I uninstalled the app.

Comment: Yes, but mostly when I change my build configuration and redeploy it after sometime like 5-10 mins then app gets deployed. Since its been few days so I am assuming even after restarting the system the registry entries didn't get removed. Which shouldn't be happening.

Comment: It shouldn't happen. But I do noticed, sometimes when I run the UWP test, the test package deployed to Windows might be locked as well, and I will get deployment errors. Apparently, there are some tooling problems which are really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the Update 2, but I still get this error.

I found a workaround, which works for me:

Open your **Package.appxmanifest** in Visual Studio 2015, **Just change the Package name**, it will update the Package family name as well.

Looks like you will get brand new entries in the registry, and so that you app can be registered and activated.